# how to make cities as subdomains without creating sub-folder in shared hosting?

Tags: php, mysql, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am working on classified site with PHP and MySql for that.

when user select their city that time i want to change website url like this

cityname.domain.com

anybody know how to do this

Comment: Have you added subdomains to your DNS and simply redirected to that subdomain?

Comment: Depends on the shared hosting, if you set up your *.example.com DNS records, and your hosting provider has a virtualhost definition with *.example.com, all that's left for you to do is detect the current domain in use with for example inspecting `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` with php.

Comment: If you want to create sub domain without creating folder. Use htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Referring to this [walkthru](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9191/29/how-do-i-create-a-wildcard-subdomain-in-cpanel):

1) Log in your cPanel

2) Navigate to the menu ‘Subdomains’ under 'Domains' section

[image]

3) Create a subdomain‘*’ pointing it to the necessary folder ( you will need to specify the path in the field ‘Document Root’ ).

3) Create a subdomain‘*’ pointing it to the necessary folder ( you will need to specify the path in the field ‘Document Root’ ).

[image]

5) Make sure that there is an A record for *.yourdomain.com created and pointed to the server IP address ( it could coincide with the IP address of your main domain or ftp.yourdomain.com is pointed to).

[image]

6) Now you will need to wait until the propagation is over ( it should take N seconds, where N – is TTL for this A record; you can edit it manually and reduce the number to speed up the process ) and then the wildcard subdomain will work correctly.

Comment: Great answer, I just hope the OP has cpanel on their server :)

Comment: Using PHP on a shared server, odds are he does.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard DNS is what you need. Ask your hosting company or use free dns provider like cloudflare :)

Sorry not allowed to add comment yet :)